# How to properly graph with Java JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I am making a GUI graph that retrieves data from a website and graphs it as some practice. The JPanel I am drawing the graph in was not in the right scale, so i flipped the axis.

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
//Flip scale
g.scale(1, -1);
g.translate(0, -getHeight());
```

This allows me to use an origin at 0,0.

The problem I have is I wanted to display the actual number on top of the graph but it is obviously not in the right spot.
[(Picture of what is it doing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6RBq.png)
How would I go about reversing the scale briefly so I can update the text in the right spot?

[image]

Comment: All you've done is mirrored the context (i.e. flipped it), so anything you render is also flipped.  To my mind, I'd create an API which took your "graph points" and mapped to the "view points"

Comment: No, because again, you'd be changing coordinate space, you'd still end up needing to map the graph space to the view space

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh okay, I could also probably just stack another JPanel on top of this one?

Comment: You could, again, you're still converting from one contextual space to another